# java application login system, mysql cannot find table

Tags: java, mysql

i am trying to connect my java application remotely. Connect to database is successful, but after i type user name and password and click login i get error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySqlSyntaxErrorException: table '...' does not exist.

I am assuming problem is here: Select * from login where username=? and password=?";
I don't know how to find table name from remote database, because login is incorrect name.

Comment: show us the whole code

Comment: Hello i don't have access to code at the moment, question is do i need login mysql file if i connect to database remotely?